# I am not sure what type of quotes to use in a bash script

Tags: linux, command-line, bash-scripting

I am working on a script. I am having it call a program that has an input directory.

The program looks like this if executing it from command line

`/path/to/program -c /path/to/config -d "path/to/directory"`

I am using a varible for the directory path. `"${name}"` the problem I am having is the program is expecting double quotes for the directory path. I have to use the double quotes in my variable to cover spaces etc.

```
find $SRC -type d -name '*' | while read name;
do
   $program -c $pgm_config -d "${name}";
done
```

The script is kind of working. The program is picking up the directory but it seems to be picking up everything else in the folder too. Single files etc. I am sure this is either really wrong or I am missing something simple. I have tried a couple different ways to see if I could just figure it out with trial and error. `""${name}""` `'"${name}"'` with no luck

Comment: What about `\""$name"\"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to use escape character or `\` this when you want to use symbols that are considered part of syntax.

```
find $SRC -type d -name \* | while read name;
    do
        $program -c $pgm_config -d \"${name}\";
    done
```

remember that this will look hidden directories as well like those which their name starts with a `.`.

Comment: It is close, it is only stating the first word of the directory

Comment: what do you mean by first word of the directory?

Comment: User error. I got it working. Thanks for the help.